# Magento 2 cookie not set when full cache enable

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, full-page-cache, cookie, helper

I have created one helper file that get, set and delete cookie.
This helper file I called in observer to set cookie.
The helper file called but cookie not set when full cache enabled.

```
<?php

namespace Hs\Mageenhancement\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Cookie extends AbstractHelper
{   
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_cookieManager;
    protected $_cookieMetadataFactory;
    protected $_sessionManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get data from cookie
     *
     * @return value
     */
    public function get($name)
    {
        return $this->_cookieManager->getCookie($name);
    }

    /**
     * Set data to cookie in remote address
     *
     * @param [string] $name    [name of cookie]
     * @param [string] $value    [value of cookie]
     * @param integer  $duration [duration for cookie] [Default value 30 days]
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function set($name, $value, $duration = 2592000)
    {
        //echo $name . ' ' . $value . ' ' . $this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath() . ' ' . $this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain();
        $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            $name,
            $value,
            $metadata
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake or any other way to set a cookie with full cache module?

Comment: what observer are you using?

Comment: @Marius  `<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
  <observer name="mageenhancement_tracking_settings" instance="Hs\Mageenhancement\Observer\TrackingObserver" />
 </event>` observer use.

Answer (score 1):

The page cache process method in vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php clears the set-cookie header

You'll need to find an event that fires after this to set a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Chirs Rutledge,

This solution is successfully implemented after consulting Chirs Rutledge's answer.

Create observer for event `controller_front_send_response_before`

File `Your_Module/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="set_member_email_cookie" instance="Your\Module\Observer\ControllerFrontSendResponseObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File `app/code/Your/Module/Observer/ControllerFrontSendResponseObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

class ControllerFrontSendResponseObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CookieManagerInterface
     */
    protected $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $sessionConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        ConfigInterface $sessionConfig
    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->sessionConfig = $sessionConfig;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setSameSite('Lax')
            ->setPath($this->sessionConfig->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionConfig->getCookieDomain())
            ->setDuration($this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime())
            ->setSecure(false)
            ->setHttpOnly(false);

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            'key',
            'value',
            $metadata
        );
    }
}
```